# Only send one email with all the errors using NLog with Console Application using C#

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to send only one email with all the errors I get from my C# Console Application.

I have the Targets:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="HeelpAdsImport_log" fileName="${basedir}/logs/HeelpAdsImport-${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true} ${message}" />

<target name="HeelpAdsImport_patrick_email" xsi:type="Mail"
        smtpServer="XXXXX"
        smtpPort="25"
        smtpAuthentication="Basic"
        smtpUserName="YYYYYY"
        smtpPassword="*ZZZZZZ"
        enableSsl="false"
        from="DDDDDDDDDD"
        to="EEEEEEEEEEE"
        layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true} ${message}"
      />
```

I have an Info rule and an Error rule:

```
<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="HeelpAdsImport_log" />

<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="HeelpAdsImport_patrick_email" />
```

I have several calls in the code for each other:

```
logger.Log(LogLevel.Info, " ----- New Ad Success! - auto.id: " + auto.id + " | auto.plate: " + auto.plate);

logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, "| continue error #4 - auto.id: " + auto.id);
```

Comment: So... what's the problem with the email?

Comment: Hi thanks, I receive an email everytime I call logger.Log(LogLevel.Error... and I call it several times in the process, but I only want to receive one email at the end of the process

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use a [BufferingWrapper](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target) for your email target to batch multiple log entries into one email. It supports batching for a specified span of time (set `flushTimeout` in milliseconds) and/or for a specified number of log entries (set `bufferSize` to the number of entries).

**Edit:** Wrap your current target inside a `<target type="BufferingWrapper">` like so:

```
<target xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
          name="MailBuffer"
          slidingTimeout="false"
          bufferSize="100"
          flushTimeout="-1">
    <target name="HeelpAdsImport_patrick_email" xsi:type="Mail"
            smtpServer="XXXXX"
            smtpPort="25"
            smtpAuthentication="Basic"
            smtpUserName="YYYYYY"
            smtpPassword="*ZZZZZZ"
            enableSsl="false"
            from="DDDDDDDDDD"
            to="EEEEEEEEEEE"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite:className=true:includeSourcePath=true:methodName=true} ${message}${newline}"
          />
</target>
```

**Edit 2:** Do you call [LogManager.Flush()](http://nlog-project.org/documentation/v2.0.1/html/M_NLog_LogManager_Flush.htm) before exiting your program?

**Edit 3:** The [${newline}](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Newline-Layout-Renderer) layout renderer should produce a line break in your email (at the end of the `layout` attribute above).

Comment: Hi thanks, but where do I set the "BufferingWrapper" and "wrappedTargetType" in my code to Buffer first and send in the end?

Comment: Hi, it seems that when the number of entries set in bufferSize is not reached, the email at the end is not sended

Comment: Great! it's working fine now! Just one last question, how can I break the line in the email? it's not make a new line, only in the file

Comment: I've added a newline layout renderer at the end of the layout attribute - that should produce a new line in your email.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! ;) I get "You may award your bounty in 18 hours." :(

Comment: Yes, you can't award a bounty within the first 24 hours after posting it.

Comment: Just a small reminder: be sure to change your target to the name of the wrapper, not your original mail target ;) even though it's nested, it will still accept it directly and not buffer :)